# UITableView redrawing without image and cell replaced

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I've got the following code which should put an image in the top section/cell and then text in the others. I think the issue is the code trying to reuse the cell when it goes off the screen but i can't work out what I should be changing. You can see a video of the problem here:

http://screencast.com/t/OoQWMI5zCKVc

The code is as follows:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{      
    static NSString *CellIdentifierText = @"TextCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierImage = @"ImageCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage] autorelease];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,180)];                
            imageView.tag = 1;
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];
            [cell addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierText];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage] autorelease];
        }      
        if(indexPath.section == 1)          
            cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       
        else if(indexPath.section ==2)
            cell.textLabel.text = [arryAddressInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        else if(indexPath.section == 3)         
            cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      
        else if(indexPath.section == 4)
            cell.textLabel.text = @"REPLACE ME WITH ICONS";

        return cell;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new instance of a `UITableViewCell` that will be displaying text, you use the wrong identifier:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:**CellIdentifierImage**] autorelease];
```

This results in one of your cells that has been populated with text (but without an image) to be cached by the `UITableView` for the `CellIdentifierImage` identifier. So when you ask (in section 0) for a cell with that identifier, you're actually getting one back that has been populated with only text.

Comment: You beut! Thanks a lot, looked at that for so long

Comment: Haha no problem, sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.